# LIKE [0-9] much slower than LIKE %

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a somewhat complex view that selects a bunch of items and the amount of stock they have remaining. I want to narrow down the result set to items codes that conform to a pattern so that unwanted items are filtered out.

The item codes that I want to include are formatted as a 4 digit number, followed by a hyphen followed by another 4 digit number

```
1234-0001
```

I also want to include item numbers that are formatted as an 13-digit number (an ISBN which starts with 978), followed by a hyphen, followed by another 2 digit number.

```
9781234567890-01
```

Originally I planned to use the below, which would match all item codes that included a hyphen in.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Vw_Stock 
WHERE ItemCode LIKE '%-%'
```

Unfortunately not all of our item codes are that uniform and people have sporadically used hyphens in items that do not conform to the two accepted formats above, so I switched to the following.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Vw_Stock 
WHERE ItemCode LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
OR ItemCode LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]'
```

The query originally took 1 second and now it takes roughly 3 minutes 50 seconds. Why does it take so much longer? And is there a more efficient way for me to query against the item formats identified?

Comment: It's the `OR`, I believe.

Comment: look at the Query execution plan

Comment: regex can be pretty costly. Out of curiosity, how well does it perform if you have a where clause like this: `isnumeric(replace(ItemCode, '-', '')) = 1`? Additionally, will your ItemCode have a lot of non-numeric values?

Comment: Does itemCode have an index ?

Comment: It may or may not help if you do `WHERE ItemCode LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%' AND (ItemCode LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
OR ItemCode LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]')`. May be worth a try.

Comment: @GSerg if I remove the `OR` and the latter statement then the query goes down to 2 minutes 40 seconds, but still far too long.

Comment: Your comparison is invalid. Your first query does not generate the same resultset as your second, so comparing them is pointless. Your second query requires that each and every character be compared to 2 different masks. There are things you might do with the view or the tables involved that might help, but you did not indicate that this was an option. You might try using a union with a single query for each condition in your current where clause. And perhaps the revisiting the view might offer improvements.

Comment: I strongly think this is related to the execution plan of the underlying view.  You need to look at the execution plans for the two queries.